# Angular : issue in my directive to get the original html content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I try too create a directive with angular. My goal is too get the original content from my html file in the compile or link function of my directive. Then update this content and for finish change the original content by the updated content in my template of my directive.

For exemple this is my index.html:

```
<my-directive> Hey this is my original content that I try to get! </my-directive>
```

This is my directive :

```
        .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            transclude: false,               
            template: '{{UpdatedContent}}',
            compile: function(tElement, tAttr) {
                console.log(tElement[0]);
            },
             ...
```

The probleme is that in my compile function or link I can't get my original content each time I tried to look the tElement object I get the "{{UpdatedContent}}".

**UPDATE : ANSWER**

In fact the solution is to use the function transcludeFn of the compile function.

Here an exemple who works :

```
     compile: function(elem, attrs, transcludeFn) {
     var markdownContent = {};    
     transcludeFn(elem, function(clone) { 
     /* clone is element containing html that will be transcludded*/
        console.log (clone.text());   
                });
```

My "clone.text()" is my original html. 
I hope this will help some of you!!

Answer (score 1):

You should set `transclude : true`, you should **not** do this: `template: '{{UpdatedContent}}'`.

If you want to get html of element on which your directive were placed in the link function just call:

```
tElement.html()
```

Btw. you always get `{{UpdatedContent}}` because you literally set it to be your template.

**UPDATE** Working [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/mZ0wxGwGTYd19B62VY4k?p=preview).

Comment: So it's not possible to get only the original content? Because element.html() will return the html of the template.

Comment: @FlavienBert you should probably use `ng-transclude`. Not sure what you want to achieve. Look at the plnkr (I updated my answer).

Comment: In your plunker you don't use directive.. The trouble if I use ng-transclude is that I will display the same content that the original. I want to update this content for exemple change all the "e" by "a" and then display the new content only. That make sense??

Comment: @FlavienBert sorry i did not save the plnkr -- that was the default one.

Comment: @FlavienBert now it is working -- you probably do not need to use `ng-transclude`.

Comment: Oki this works because you don't use any template but if you use a template your element.html() send you back the template... but I have find a solution I will update my question for write the answer.

Comment: @FlavienBert update the plnkr. it can be extended and improved further: especially if you want to deal with the dynamic content recursively. But your solution with transcludeFn is better!